# ElasticSearch not getting up - node.lock error

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm facing issue while starting ElasticSearch which was working fine sometime back.

I'm deploying it on Kubernetes.

Now, everytime I try to start it, the pod throws this error:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-09-24T13:09:38,995+0000", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.b.JNANatives", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "metrics-es-779d8667c8-tgn9w",  "message": "Unable to lock JVM Memory: error=12, reason=Cannot allocate memory"  }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-09-24T13:09:38,998+0000", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.b.JNANatives", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "metrics-es-779d8667c8-tgn9w",  "message": "This can result in part of the JVM being swapped out."  }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-09-24T13:09:38,999+0000", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.b.JNANatives", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "metrics-es-779d8667c8-tgn9w",  "message": "Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK, soft limit: 16777216, hard limit: 16777216"  }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-09-24T13:09:38,999+0000", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.b.JNANatives", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "metrics-es-779d8667c8-tgn9w",  "message": "These can be adjusted by modifying /etc/security/limits.conf, for example: \n\t# allow user 'elasticsearch' mlockall\n\telasticsearch soft memlock unlimited\n\telasticsearch hard memlock unlimited"  }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-09-24T13:09:38,999+0000", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.b.JNANatives", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "metrics-es-779d8667c8-tgn9w",  "message": "If you are logged in interactively, you will have to re-login for the new limits to take effect."  }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-09-24T13:09:39,699+0000", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "metrics-es-779d8667c8-tgn9w",  "message": "uncaught exception in thread [main]" , 
"stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to obtain node locks, tried [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data]] with lock id [0]; maybe these locations are not writable or multiple nodes were started without increasing [node.max_local_storage_nodes] (was [1])?",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:163) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:115) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to obtain node locks, tried [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data]] with lock id [0]; maybe these locations are not writable or multiple nodes were started without increasing [node.max_local_storage_nodes] (was [1])?",
"at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:297) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:272) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:252) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:211) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:211) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:325) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"... 6 more",
"Caused by: java.io.IOException: failed to obtain lock on /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0",
"at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment$NodeLock.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:219) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:267) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:272) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:252) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:211) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:211) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:325) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"... 6 more",
"Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/node.lock: Read-only file system",
"at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:100) ~[?:?]",
"at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111) ~[?:?]",
"at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116) ~[?:?]",
"at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:182) ~[?:?]",
"at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:292) ~[?:?]",
"at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:345) ~[?:?]",
"at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:125) ~[lucene-core-8.0.0.jar:8.0.0 2ae4746365c1ee72a0047ced7610b2096e438979 - jimczi - 2019-03-08 11:58:55]",
"at org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:41) ~[lucene-core-8.0.0.jar:8.0.0 2ae4746365c1ee72a0047ced7610b2096e438979 - jimczi - 2019-03-08 11:58:55]",
"at org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:45) ~[lucene-core-8.0.0.jar:8.0.0 2ae4746365c1ee72a0047ced7610b2096e438979 - jimczi - 2019-03-08 11:58:55]",
"at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment$NodeLock.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:212) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:267) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:272) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:252) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:211) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:211) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:325) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]",
"... 6 more"] }
```

Any suggestions what might be the issue?

Comment: The wrapped error states: `Read-only file system`. Do you have enough spare space on your file system?

Comment: Check this https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-solve-node-lock-error-in-elasticsearch/51650

Comment: Add your yaml code.